# How do I get VSCode to recognize current package Javascript imports?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, javascript-intellisense

VSCode intellisense is great, when I import a javascript function like

```
import func from './file';
```

vs code will give me a helpful dialog with its arguments from jsdoc. This is because I'm using a relative file path.

However, if I'm working with my current package, lets call it "public" as listed in my package.json, and try to reference a file using its absolute path, the intellisense doesn't pick up on the file.

```
// import the same file as above, but using absolute path
// public is the name of the current npm package
import func from 'public/subfolder/file';
```

intellisense no longer appears.

Is this a bug or a configuration issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Step1

Create a `jsconfig.json` file to indicate a JavaScript project within vs code, just go to the bottom of vs code and click on green bulb icon.

It will ask you to create `jsconfig.json`. Create `jsconfig.json` file which will contain the following code.

```
//jsconfig.json
{
 // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=759670
 // for the documentation about the jsconfig.json format
 "compilerOptions": {
 "target": "es6",
 "module": "commonjs",
 "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
 },
 "exclude": [
 "node_modules",
 "bower_components",
 "jspm_packages",
 "tmp",
 "temp"
 ]
}
```

[image]

Step2
[image]
Install typings globally for downloading TypeScript Definition files (typings) for node modules like express, mongoose, angular etc.

`npm install typings --global`

TypeScript definition files are written in TypeScript to provide a VS IntelliSense experience for the functions and it's parameters. Let's install typings for express as given below:

`typings insall dt~express --global`

Let's try the coding experience for express. You will see the great intelliSense for express.

[image]

Comment: To me, seems like the key is `"module": "CommonJS",` .

Answer (score 0):

#### solution

*4 different ways*::

In your `jsconfig.json` > `compilerOptions`::

*(recommended solution)*

- Set **`"moduleResolution": "node",`**

*(other solution)*

- Use **`"module": "CommonJS"`**, -- dont use `"module": "ES6"` or others;

  - (Doesnt matter what `"target": "XXX"` is)
- **Remove** (comment out) both `"module": "XXX"` & **`"target": "XXX"`**
- Directly specify the path in your import (which Op wants to avoid)

  - eg: `import XXX from '../node_modules/core-decorators/index.js'`

#### reference

> [vscode will not auto import node modules packages correctly] https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30472