# JSDoc comments not showing on absolute path import

Tags: javascript, import, visual-studio-code, jsdoc

I'm adding JSDoc function documentation and am having trouble getting my documentation comments to appear when importing the functions with an absolute page path.

JSDoc function:

```
/**
* Adds two numbers together and returns that value
* @param {number} a
* @param {number} b
* @return {number} returns the value of a plus b
*/
function addNums (a, b) {
 return a + b;
}

export { addNums }
```

Works with relative page path:

`import { addNums } from './addNums'`

Doesn't work with absolute page path:

`import { addNums } from '~/lib/helpers/addNums'`

Screen shots of what it looks like when I change the path from absolute to relative in my actual code:

**Absolute page path:**
[image: Absolute page path]
**Relative page path:**
[image: Relative page path]
I've tried the solution listed on this SO thread: [How do I get VSCode to recognize current package Javascript imports?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48709594/how-do-i-get-vscode-to-recognize-current-package-javascript-imports)

Unfortunately that did not work so Im wondering how to get JSDoc to recognize my absolute page paths and not the relative page paths that I define upon import. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out. So this was an issue with the way we configured our webpack to recognize the `~`

```
//webpack config

     config.resolve.alias = {
      ...config.resolve.alias,
      '~': path.resolve(__dirname)
    }
```

I believe normally JSdoc doesn't have a problem resolving absolute file paths but in my case I added a tsconfig.json file:

```
   ///tsconfig.json

   {
    "compilerOptions": {
        "allowJs": true,
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "~/*": ["*"]
        }
    }
}
```

This did the trick. Apologize if this confused anyone else, I wasn't aware of the webpack config until after this post but in the off-chance someone else has a similar configuration and is trying to get JSDoc to work, this is the solution!